# std::sort Doesn't work for User-Defined Object with oveloaded < operator

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, stl

I am writing a class to test the efficient of different sorting algorithms (for a college course), and of the algorithms I'm supposed to test is the STL sort. To measure efficiency, we've defined a class Integer that holds and integer value, and also allows us to increment a global variable each time it is compared or assigned. I then have a driver class which tests the std::sort call on multiple vectors of integers. I have overloaded the '<' operator in my Integer class, and it conforms to strict weak ordering (at least I'm pretty sure it does). Every time I call sort, however, I get a segmentation fault. I really can't figure out why this is happening, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Integer.cpp**

```
#include "Integer.h"

int Integer_count;

//Default Constructor
Integer::Integer() {
    val = 0;
}

//Specified Constructor
Integer::Integer(int x) {
    val = x;
}

//Copy-Constructor
Integer::Integer(const Integer &cp) {
    Integer_count++;
    val = cp.val;
}

//Return the Integer's value
int Integer::value() {
    return val;
}

//Less-than (<) operator overload
bool Integer::operator < (const Integer& obj) const {
    Integer_count++;
    return (val < obj.val);
}

//Assignment (=) operator overload
void Integer::operator = (const Integer& obj) {
    Integer_count++;
    val=obj.val;
}
```

**driver.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include "Integer.h"
#include "Sorter.cpp"    
srand (time(NULL)); //Seed the random number generator

    std::vector<Integer> one;
    std::vector<Integer> two;
    std::vector<Integer> three;
    std::vector<Integer> four;
    std::vector<Integer> five;


    for(int i=0; i<10000; i++){
        one[i] = Integer(i);
        two[i] = Integer(10000-i);
        three[i] = Integer(rand() % (10000+1));
        four[i] = Integer(rand() % (10000+1));
        five[i] = Integer(rand() % (10000+1));
    }


    //Sort function called from the STL
    //Sorted Array
    std::sort(one.begin(), one.end());
    std::cout << "STL for Sorted Array: " << Integer_count << std::endl;
```

Basically, I think the std::sort function is not using the overloaded operator from my Integer class, which is messing up the stack. I don't know for certain is this is the error however, and can't seem to resolve it.

Comment: You are not allocating any space for your std::vectors. `one[i]` does not create a new element . Use `one.push_back(Integer(i));`

Comment: vector[] does not insert new elements - use push_back instead

Comment: To reserve vector space write `std::vector<Integer> one(10000)` for instance. Alternative: `one.reserve(10000)` and in the loop `one.push_back(Integer(i))` instead of the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::vector::operator[]` never inserts a new element into the container and no bounds checking is performed ([vector/operator_at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)). If you access an element that is out of bounds leads to undefined behaviour which is your case.

You must use `std::vector::emplace_back` or `std::vector::push_back`, other option is to use the constructor `explicit vector<T>(size_type count);` that constructs the container with `count` default-inserted instances of `T`:

First option:

```
std::vector<Integer> one;
one.reserve(10000);
std::vector<Integer> two;
two.reserve(10000);
std::vector<Integer> three;
three.reserve(10000);
std::vector<Integer> four;
four.reserve(10000);
std::vector<Integer> five;
five.reserve(10000);

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    one.emplace_back(i);
    two.emplace_back(10000 - i);
    three.emplace_back(rand() % (10000+1));
    four.emplace_back(rand() % (10000+1));
    five.emplace_back(rand() % (10000+1));
}
```

Second option:

```
std::vector<Integer> one(10000);
std::vector<Integer> two(10000);
std::vector<Integer> three(10000);
std::vector<Integer> four(10000);
std::vector<Integer> five(10000);

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    one[i] = Integer(i);
    two[i] = Integer(10000-i);
    three[i] = Integer(rand() % (10000+1));
    four[i] = Integer(rand() % (10000+1));
    five[i] = Integer(rand() % (10000+1));
}
```

And `std::sort(one.begin(), one.end())` must work.

Comment: Thanks so much - was trying to hack it together quick and forgot the simplest syntax. My bad :)

Answer (score 1):

Your values for your vector[i] are not allocated. Hence, accessing vector values (e.g `one[999999]`) that **are out of bounds** leads to undefined behaviour.

Use [**`push_back()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) for your **`std:::vector`** to allocate and assign the values to your vectors:

```
for(int i=0; i<10000; i++){
    one.push_back(Integer(i));
    two.push_back(Integer(10000-i));
    three.push_back(Integer(rand() % (10000+1)));
    four.push_back(Integer(rand() % (10000+1)));
    five.push_back(Integer(rand() % (10000+1)));
}
```

That will solve the segmentatio fault.
As for sorting, once you have values.

`std::sort(one.begin(), one.end())` **[sorts by default using `operator<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort#Example)** so leave it as it is.

Comment: Typo, quick answer. Thanks @4386427

Answer (score 0):

You didn't push/append elements in vector. Without allocating space or pushing back, you can't add element in vector this way (My clang compiler would yield runtime error due to bad allocation/array out of bound). Use `push_back` instead.

To quick test -

```
std::vector<Integer> arr{Integer(1), Integer(4), Integer(3)};
sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());

// now print Integer_count
```